# Any database with the prec weight for the row and for which we can store * for a value

Tags: database, weighted

Any database with the prec weight for the row and every column has some weight and also for which we can store * for a value. When we query with any column it should return atleast the row which has * in that column.

Need to find a database which could support this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.